# How to build a logit classification table in R when values are deleted...?

Tags: r

I'm a french stud and i'm trying to make a classification table on a Logit model.

Problem, R returns me an error when i'm trying to build it, because the lenght of the glm don't match with the lenght of my dependent variable.

What i tried to do... :

1.

```
>reg4=glm(buyEV3~lvlEtu+typecar1+typecar2+typecar3+bonus+goodForEnv+cheaper+knowEV,data=bdd,family=binomial(link="logit"))
> reg4
[...]
Degrees of Freedom: 230 Total (i.e. Null);  222 Residual
  (85 observations deleted due to missingness)
[...]
>mysteps=step(reg4,buyEV3~lvlEtu+typecar1+typecar2+typecar3+bonus+goodForEnv+cheaper+knowEV,data=bdd,family=binomial(link="logit"))
[...]
> classDF=data.frame(response=bdd$buyEV,predicted=round(fitted(mysteps),0))
    Error in data.frame(response = bdd$buyEV, predicted = round(fitted(mysteps),  :
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 316, 231
```

2.

```
> library(QuantPsyc)
> ClassLog(reg4,bdd$buyEV,cut=.5)
Error in table(predict(MOD, type = "response") > cut, resp) :
  all arguments must have the same length
```

How to fix this problem ?

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: A classification table is at odds with the goals of logistic regression.

Answer (score 0):

Refering to attempt 1. Since only complete observations are included in your logistic model "(85 observations deleted due to missingness)" the length of your dependent varable in the original dataset and the number of values supplied by running `fitted()`will differ by the same amount.

Extracting the dependent variable from observations actually included in the model will do the trick

```
classDF=data.frame(response=reg4$model$buyEV,predicted=round(fitted(mysteps),0))
```

Where `glmobject$model$variable` is what's important in similar situations.